# Posts Awaiting Review - Wrong Count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

For the last two weeks, my menu bar shows three posts waiting for review. When I check all of the review queues, there are no reviews pending. When the count goes above 3, then there are that many reviews, minus three, pending.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's complicated is that there are reviews that are still *in progress* but which aren't in *your personal* available reviews. There can be two reasons for this:

- You have done a review task, but not enough other people have for that particular task to be completed.
- You pressed the “Skip” button on a review task.

The review count in the header shows *reviews that need attention*, not necessarily those that *you* can advance — my understanding is that this is both for performance reasons (avoid expensive database queries if you're not actively reviewing) and [to report on the health of the review system in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many).

Comment: @GlennW9IQ That used to confuse me too, before I realized this. :-)

Comment: Understood, but it has been stuck at 3 for nearly a week. My observation with pressing the Skip button is that it is removed from the review count.

Comment: @MikeWaters Sorry, Mike should have tagged the above comment.

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I should have tagged your comment?

Comment: Now the count is up to 8 with nothing in the queue. The semaphore is nearly useless.